# How can I check if a point is inside a n-dimensional parallelogram?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

like the title says: let's say I have a parallelogram (or parallelotope?) generated by $n$ bases in a space $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Given a point $t \in \mathbb{R^n}$, how can I check whether $t$ is inside the parallelogram?
In 3-D I would, for each pair of bases:

- Take two bases $b_i, b_j$
- Project the point onto the plane spun by the bases, using the remaining base $b_w$ as direction
- 2-D check if the point is inside the parallelogram

How can I generalize it in 4 dimensions?

Thank you!

Comment: (1) I assume by "bases" you mean "basis vectors". A basis is not one vector but a collection of vectors. (2) I think your 3D method is not correct. (3) The parallelogram has a shape and orientation described by the $n$ vectors, but what is its location?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: if you change basis, the problem reduces to the trivial special case of the hypercube.

Comment: Alternative hint: how do you know when a vector is in the convex hull of some other vectors?

Comment: @William - We're given $n$ vectors, not $2^n$ vectors, so presumably they represent edges, not vertices. The convex hull is not applicable.

Comment: @mr_e_man (1) Ops, sorry! Yes, a collection of vectors. (2) Why? It's like taking a parallelopiped and look at it from front, top, and right (3) The basis starts from the origin, so one of the vertices is the origin

Comment: Find the coordinates of point $t$ with the respect to the basis formed by the given vectors. If all coordinates are between $0$ and $1$ then $t$ is inside.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I will give a shot, thank you!

Comment: @mr_e_man given $n$ basis vectors, it is not terribly difficult to find the vertices of the parallelopiped they mutually define. In fact, there is a bijection between these $2^n$ vertices and the $2^n$ possible sums of the basis vectors.

Comment: @narger - (2) If the parallelepiped is not rectangular, when you look at it from a direction orthogonal to one face, you can still see some other faces with non-zero area. But if you're projecting in the direction of an edge, not in the direction orthogonal to a face, then it's correct after all.